# Cross-platform Unicode font

Tags: html, css, unicode, fonts

I am currently working on a responsive page which uses unicode symbols on certain elements and I would like them to have the same "look". As I understand, each browser and each operating system have different fonts for unicode symbols, and I noticed that the font-family property was not helping.

My biggest problem right now is that all the unicode symbols that I use show up as colored emojis on smartphones, which often ruins the page's design. Is there any way to fix that? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question can be split into two:

1. How to not worry about client-side fonts: web fonts
2. How to use emoji/pictograms without browser changing the rendering: css icon font

The latter part is more relevant as you are specifically dealing with emoji.

## Web fonts

Web fonts would solve the cross-system compatibility issue. These are fonts that are served to the browser. [Google fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) is a good place to start —it is actually weird to see how much of the web uses them.
If your unicode is more than just Greek or CJK and uses, say, runes, you will need to make your own web font (which is easy, Googling gives many [web servers](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) and [guides](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp)), which takes advantage of `@font-face` rule ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_typography#Web_fonts)). One serious drawback to the latter is that there is a copyright problem if you use a font you found on some depository or on your machine, so that is something worth looking out for.

## Icon font library

An icon font library is a stylesheet library (with a font) that inserts an icon after an empty element with a class named for that icon, *e.g.* in [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) `<i class="fa fa-hand-spock-o"></i>`.
As emoji are a recent addition and the support is more than patchy, websites and browsers add the support themselves, often coloring them (*e.g.* [Chromoji extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromoji-emojis-for-googl/)). Consequently, I strongly suggest using an icon font library.
I am partial to [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) —*e.g.* [an academic tool of mine](http://www.mutanalyst.com/)—, but there are loads of other options, some are:

- [Bootstrap's Glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons)
- [Typicons](http://www.typicons.com/)
- [Fontello](http://fontello.com/) allows a mishmash of various icon font libraries (a longer list can be found there).

If however, the icon you are looking for is absent, you can create an icon font library using one of the many web resources (*eg* [iconmoon.io](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select)). For the images themselves, [flaticon](http://www.flaticon.com/) has large collection of icons that can be converted to a icon library, which saves you time from having to slave away in illustrator.

Comment: I am actually using HTML entities for a few symbols like &#128100;  &#128296;  and &#128213;
I am not quite sure what font my browser or operating system (W7) is using since trying to change the font does not change the look of the symbols. I have tried several web safe font combinations before.


[This is how my symbols actually show up in Chrome](http://imgur.com/1kO1y4R)

Comment: Ah. Emoji. In that case, I would strongly recommend using icons, such as [FontAwesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), [Bootstrap's glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons).

Comment: Also, custom icon fonts can be made easily —that is once you have the icon itself, but there are lots cool resources like [flaticon](http://www.flaticon.com/), that save you time from slaving away in Illustrator.

Comment: I had no idea custom fonts could be made so easily now. I will definitely use that instead, thanks!

Comment: I exanded my original answer to reflect the discussion here. I hope it helps.

Comment: I only needed a couple of icons so I ended up grabbing a few from flaticon and bundled the svg files into an icon font on iconmoon. I'll probably use FontAwesome for later projects, all are really cool and useful tools! Thanks again for the detailed answer, much appreciated.

Comment: Glad it helped. Nothing else needed, _i.e._ question _answered_? ;)